# Validate time field while selecting the option in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying with angularjs where can validate time field . how can i validate dropdown field by current time? In the select option i have given min={{currentdate | "hh:mm::ss"}}. but is not validating,  below is my code

> HTML PAGE:

```
 <h6 class="text-left">Time<span class="error"> *</span></h6>  
   <select class='Select-button' name='time' id='time' ng-model='saverem.time' type='text' placeholder="Select Time" required  min="08:00:00" > 
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="08:00:00">08:00 AM</option>
            <option value="08:15:00">08:15 AM</option>
            <option value="08:30:00">08:30 AM</option>
            <option value="08:45:00">08:45 AM</option>
            <option value="09:00:00">09:00 AM</option>
            <option value="09:15:00">09:15 AM</option>
            <option value="09:30:00">09:30 AM</option>
            <option value="09:45:00">09:45 AM</option>
            <option value="10:00:00">10:00 AM</option>
            <option value="10:15:00">10:15 AM</option>
            <option value="10:30:00">10:30 AM</option>
            <option value="10:45:00">10:45 AM</option>
            <option value="11:00:00">11:00 AM</option>
            <option value="11:15:00">11:15 AM</option>
            <option value="11:30:00">11:30 AM</option>
            <option value="11:45:00">11:45 AM</option>
            <option value="12:00:00">12:00 PM</option>
            <option value="12:15:00">12:15 PM</option>
            <option value="12:30:00">12:30 PM</option>
            <option value="12:45:00">12:45 PM</option>
            <option value="13:00:00">01:00 PM</option>
            <option value="13:15:00">01:15 PM</option>
            <option value="13:30:00">01:30 PM</option>
            <option value="13:45:00">01:45 PM</option>
            <option value="14:00:00">02:00 PM</option>
            <option value="14:15:00">02:15 PM</option>
            <option value="14:30:00">02:30 PM</option>
            <option value="14:45:00">02:45 PM</option>
            <option value="15:00:00">03:00 PM</option>
            <option value="15:15:00">03:15 PM</option>
            <option value="15:30:00">03:30 PM</option>
            <option value="15:45:00">03:45 PM</option>
            <option value="16:00:00">04:00 PM</option>
            <option value="16:15:00">04:15 PM</option>
            <option value="16:30:00">04:30 PM</option>
            <option value="16:45:00">04:45 PM</option>
            <option value="17:00:00">05:00 PM</option>
            <option value="17:15:00">05:15 PM</option>
            <option value="17:30:00">05:30 PM</option>
            <option value="17:45:00">05:45 PM</option>
            <option value="18:00:00">06:00 PM</option>
            <option value="18:15:00">06:15 PM</option>
            <option value="18:30:00">06:30 PM</option>
            <option value="18:45:00">06:45 PM</option>
            <option value="19:00:00">07:00 PM</option>
            <option value="19:15:00">07:15 PM</option>
            <option value="19:30:00">07:30 PM</option>
            <option value="19:45:00">07:45 PM</option>
            <option value="20:00:00">08:00 PM</option>
            <option value="20:15:00">08:15 PM</option>
            <option value="20:30:00">08:30 PM</option>
            <option value="20:45:00">08:45 PM</option>
            <option value="21:00:00">09:00 PM</option>
            <option value="21:15:00">09:15 PM</option>
            <option value="21:30:00">09:30 PM</option>
            <option value="21:45:00">09:45 PM</option>
            <option value="22:00:00">10:00 PM</option>
            <option value="22:15:00">10:15 PM</option>
            <option value="22:30:00">10:30 PM</option>
            <option value="22:45:00">10:45 PM</option>
            <option value="23:00:00">11:00 PM</option>
            <option value="23:15:00">11:15 PM</option>
            <option value="23:30:00">11:30 PM</option>
            <option value="23:45:00">11:45 PM</option>
            <option value="00:00:00">12:00 AM</option>
            <option value="00:15:00">12:15 AM</option>
            <option value="00:30:00">12:30 AM</option>
            <option value="00:45:00">12:45 AM</option>
            <option value="01:00:00">01:00 AM</option>
            <option value="01:15:00">01:15 AM</option>
            <option value="01:30:00">01:30 AM</option>
            <option value="01:45:00">01:45 AM</option>
            <option value="02:00:00">02:00 AM</option>
            <option value="02:15:00">02:15 AM</option>
            <option value="02:30:00">02:30 AM</option>
            <option value="02:45:00">02:45 AM</option>
            <option value="03:00:00">03:00 AM</option>
            <option value="03:15:00">03:15 AM</option>
            <option value="03:30:00">03:30 AM</option>
            <option value="03:45:00">03:45 AM</option>
            <option value="04:00:00">04:00 AM</option>
            <option value="04:15:00">04:15 AM</option>
            <option value="04:30:00">04:30 AM</option>
            <option value="04:45:00">04:45 AM</option>
            <option value="05:00:00">05:00 AM</option>
            <option value="05:15:00">05:15 AM</option>
            <option value="05:30:00">05:30 AM</option>
            <option value="05:45:00">05:45 AM</option>
            <option value="06:00:00">06:00 AM</option>
            <option value="06:15:00">06:15 AM</option>
            <option value="06:30:00">06:30 AM</option>
            <option value="06:45:00">06:45 AM</option>
            <option value="07:00:00">07:00 AM</option>
            <option value="07:15:00">07:15 AM</option>
            <option value="07:30:00">07:30 AM</option>
            <option value="07:45:00">07:45 AM</option>            
                </select>
                <span class='error' ng-show="remform.remtime.$dirty && remform.remtime.$invalid">
                          <span ng-show="remform.remtime.$error.required">Select time</span>  
                          <span ng-show="remform.remtime.$error.min">Time cannot be older than the current date and time</span>
                </span>

               <button id="addreminder" type="submit" class="button button-block maple-button"
                      ng-click="addreminder()" 
                    ng-disabled="((remform.time.$dirty && remform.remtime.$invalid)|| (remform.time.$pristine && remform.remtime.$invalid))"> Submit </button>
```

> JS CONTROLLER:

```
  $scope.currentDate = new Date();
```

Comment: If you are using angularjs, why not use ng-options? Also I dont see any vaidation function

Comment: You need to write custom validator directive.

Comment: you should use ng-min for this..

Comment: add value in dropdown which are >= current time